# ASM find offset with code

Tags: java, assembly, bytecode, offset

I would like to find the offsets of different methods in test cases I work with. I can find where methods start and end, I look for opcodes RETURN and ARETURN (Im doing so in a class that extends a methodVisitor in the method visitInsn()), but I have not been able to find the offset where those happen in the bytecode. Any ideas?

*Just in case:*
I am working with the core API of ASM, I am aware that the tree API could help me find what I need, but the tree API makes everything go slow and use memory and I can not afford any of those, so I work with the core API

Comment: Why do you need to know the offsets?  You don't use these directly and probably should try.

Comment: I need them because I run other code that analyzes specific parts of code using the offsets, but I have to search for them my self running javap and stuff, so I just want to not have to do that anymore...

Comment: I would suggest you have a bytecode analysis tool like ASM or BCEL or Javaassist. These are designed to make it easier to write such a tool and you don't need to know the offsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the offsets per instruction, it is not a common way but it works for me. ASM does not give you the offset per instruction because usually you wont need it, but you can still get it, I had to modify classes within ASM to make my idea work.

I modified the Label class and the ClassReader class, in the second one, there is a part that creates and adds labels to the labels array only in special occasions, so I just told it to add a label per instruction, then I just call the getOffset inside a visitInsn inside a methodVisitor and, the label will be resolved and have the offset.